# where clause along with concat and <

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help me in understanding this query..

```
select * from tab1 where col5 || :bv1 < :bv2 ;
```

table tab1 contains 5 columns and values of col5 except one row are NULL and `:bv1 < :bv2` always.

When I run the above query.I see all the rows except the row where the col5 is NOT NULL.

What does `where col5 || :bv1 < :bv2 ;` mean?

And if I am not wrong `<` has higher preference than `||`

Comment: correct me if i am wrong you mean you are seeing all the rows except where the col5 data is NULL. Second please specify the type of col5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this do?

```
where col5 || :bv1 < :bv2
```

It does *exactly* what it says.  First, it concatenates `col5` and `:bv1` and then it compares them to `:bv2`.  Perhaps it would be clearer with parentheses:

```
where (col5 || :bv1) < :bv2
```

SQL "operators" are evaluated before "conditions", as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions001.htm#SQLRF52083).

So, if the values were `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`, then the comparison would be `'ab'` to `'c'`, and the result would be true.

EDIT:

Oracle treats `NULL` as an empty string in a concatenation, by default.  So, `NULL || 'a'` --> `'a'`.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Oracle doesn't allow you to treat condition results as values, so  `col5 || (:bv1 < :bv2)` is invalid.